# My Node.js + Express.js application takes 1 minute for serving static files

Tags: node.js, express

## Problem

Hi, As you can see in the image it always takes 1 minute for loading an image from my node.js + express.js application .

[image: It takes 1 minute for waiting time]

## Similar question

I also check out this question and done what it said but it didn't work for me : [Node.js + Express.js very slow serving static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106399/node-js-express-js-very-slow-serving-static-files)

## What I've done

Im using express.static for serving files and here is the code :

```
app.use('/files/', express.static('./files/'))
```

---

ّI don't know what is waiting time and why it takes 1 minute for answering my request .

Please help me.

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `app.use(express.static('files'));`?

Comment: @VirgilioGM according to this link : https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

i want to create a virtual path

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've never used this syntax. But it seems that this is intended to call a path that does not exist locally and in your case you declare the path '/files' and you want it to redirect to '/files', so that virtual path would not be necessary, right? Did you tried `app.use(express.static('files'))` or even `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'files')))` ?

Comment: @VirgilioGM I'm checking it now

Comment: I was thinking wrong about it. and it was not express problem.

The Problem was Nginx and proxy_connect_timeout , I set it to 1s and all the problem solved.

Comment: @Mahdi What it has to do with `proxy_connect_timeout`? I think lowering it might cause some requests to timeout when the node server has high load on it.

Comment: @ArashMilani It automatically sets to 60s and my problem was the waiting time for the request that was 60s , I changed `proxy_connect_timeout` to 1s and my problem solved , i think that was pure luck , I really don't know why this happened .

Comment: @Mahdi Yes the default value for `proxy_connect_timeout` is 60s and I think the default values has a reason to be there. Is the `express.static` the first middleware that your `express` app has? it looks like your node.js app is not closing the connection after sending the response to the client.

Comment: @ArashMilani Yes the `express.static` is the first middleware , shouldn't it be the first ? I've done this according to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28174029/6845743

Comment: @Mahdi Yes it is best practice to put that middleware as the first middleware. was just double-checking it.